# Python - Accessing multiple nested subfolders within a .ZIP file

Tags: python, zip, subdirectory

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find any references to it and the code I've written thus far hasn't worked.

Let's say I have a zip file called ABC.ZIP. Inside the zip file are subfolders like '20201007', '20201008', '20201009'. And within each of those subfolders there are more subfolders like "Reports001', 'Reports002', 'Reports003'. Each of those reports folders contain files whose filenames that I want to search for a pick out and extract only certain files that meet the criteria.

> ABC.ZIP >
> 20201007 >
> Reports1 >
> Files |
> Reports2 >
> Files |
> Reports3 >
> Files |
> 20201008 >
> Reports1 >
> Files |
> etc..

How can I access, through python, the subfolders in the zip file after I have already called ZipObject.namelist()? Here's what I've tries so far:

```
with ZipFile(path + "\\" + myZipFileName, 'r') as zipObject:
    listOfFolderNames = zipObject.namelist()
    for folderName in listOfFolderNames:
        with ZipFile(path + "\\" + myZipFileName + "\\" + foldername, 'r') as ZipObject1
        listofSubfolderNames1 = ZipObject.namelist()
```

The line with `ZipFile(path + "\\" + myZipFileName + "\\" + foldername, 'r') as ZipObject1` tells me there is no folder named "C:\zipfiles\ABC.ZIP\20201007"

I've tried os.walk and listdir but again, I can't seem to reference the subfolder within the zip file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Following program can be used to read only .txt files from a zip file:

```
with ZipFile ('<your zip file>','r')as zipObject:
    for i in zipObject.infolist():
        if not i.is_dir() and i.filename.endswith('.txt'):
            with zipObject.open((i.filename), 'r') as f:
                print(f.read())
```

You can try something similar to it.

Comment: Thank you! Infolist() was what I was missing.